# Access Query , get also the values without relation

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Recently started working in access as a home-assignment project.
The problem I am facing is quite simple but I don`t have any ideas on how to solve it :)

I have 2 tables - Purchases and Sales
On both of them I made 2 queries - TotalIn and TotalOut
And now base on the 2 queries I want to make one query to find what remains, but if I did not sell a type of product I bought it won`t appear there.

TotalIn Query: https://i.gyazo.com/69efe888b1fef646531237b4b5dbcf20.png

TotalOut Query: https://i.gyazo.com/99668560a1fba93d470c01639691d87c.png

This is the try for the third query :https://i.gyazo.com/d871219a5e3890af3cf06139d624ac7f.png

And this is what I get :https://i.gyazo.com/ddf802e03001df28df1ebf17b694bb32.png

The idea is that I get just those products on which I had some sales, but I would like also to have the information on those which did not have any transactions.

Thank you very much for any ideas and sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 0):

Change the join to a 'left join'. To do this, in the query design double-click the link between the two tables (or right-click and select join properties) and then select the options that says "Include ALL records from 'Stock-In' and only those records from 'Stock-Out' where the joined fields are equal."